# Setting up logging for buckets in Google Cloud storage

Tags: gsutil

Trying to set up logging on a GCS bucket. every time i enter the command to set logging i get the error below. *"Command exception: "logging" command does not support "file://" URLs. did you mean to use a gs:// URL?"* is it my test logs bucket that has the error or my bucket covered by the logging command?

[image: Image of gsutil command]

Answer (score 3):

The folder in the bucket URL and [-o logs] is causing the issue in the command that you are running.

The command should be the following:

```
gsutil logging set on -b gs://my_logging_bucket -o log_object_prefix gs://my_bucket1 gs://my_bucket2
```